# Loading key value pairs from a file to mongodb in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a file having key value pairs in the following format

```
key1:value1, key2:value2 ...
```

I want to load the file into mongodb using pymongo but I have been failing. I have tried `json.loads` but still not successful.

Is there some way to have some thing like

```
for records in file
   for each key, value in record
      Insert key, value for that specific record_id
```

Comment: You can split it first by the comma character (for each key-value pair) and then for each pair split by the colon character `:`

Comment: splitting is not a problem, I am able to insert data to mongodb

Comment: So then what is your question about? You **are** able to insert the data?

Comment: I have made an edit to the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store your values as json format in your files like

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

In myself I stored above it in demo.txt file.

Then I load using `json.load` as following

```
import json

txt = open('demo.txt', 'rb')
data = json.load(txt)
```

and the result of above is like

```
>> {u'key1': u'value1', u'key2': u'value2'}
```

for json format [help](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can of course store as JSON (see @Syed answer)

but if changing that file is not an option, you can split using ',' and ':', and create a dictionary from that:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    to_insert = {key.trim(): value.trim() for key, value in (pair.split(':') for pair in line.split(','))}
    collection.save(to_insert)
```